# Site name not visible (transparent) in chat room

Tags: bug, design, chat

Could the dev team please improve the contrast here? The site name seems to be transparent and of the same color as the background in the region enclosed in red (in the snapshot below).

[image]

Comment: It's there, but barely visible because the font colour is just about midway between the stripe colours.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yes, that's what I meant by "not visible (transparent)".